# Scripting for LUIS and QNA Maker

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

We are planning to do scripting for updating the LUIS and QNA Maker for Dev/testing/production environment. Is there any possibility of doing it in the current version of LUIS and QNA Maker?

Comment: Can you please be more detailed for what kind of scripting? Adding new Intents / Utterances from code?

Comment: Actually i was looking specifically for Continuous integration (Version control support) from LUIS which helps me in Staging environment Eg Moving my code from development to production

Answer (score 1):

LUIS has a variety of scriptable options including service management through [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azurerm.cognitiveservices/azurerm.cognitiveservices?view=azurermps-6.0.0#cognitive_services), ARM templates, and REST APIs for [authoring](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f) and [endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78).

Comment: Hey @DFBerry Thanks for an update, Actually i was looking specifically for Continuous integration (Version control support) from LUIS which helps me in Staging environment Eg Moving my code from development to production

Comment: `Actually i was looking specifically for Continuous integration (Version control support) from LUIS` Hi @VinayJayaram, it indeed provides staging&production slots and enables us to publish app to the [staging slot or the production slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp#production-and-staging-slots). Do you want to dynamically and programmatically move a app from staging to production slot?

Comment: Hi @VinayJayaram - what would moving from development to production look like? Is Fei Han correct that you mean move from stage to production or do you mean something else?

Comment: yes Fei Han is correct i am looking for scripts which can dynamically and programmatically move

Answer (score 0):

> do scripting for updating the LUIS and QNA Maker for Dev/testing/production environment.

LUIS provides [two publishing slots: Staging slot and Production slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp#production-and-staging-slots). And if you’d like to programmatically update and publish app to specified slot, you can use the following LUIS Programmatic APIs:

- [Import version to application](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5892283039e2bb0d9c2805f5)
- [Publish application](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c3b)

Besides, as far as I know, QnA Maker currently does not provide publishing slots.